# DateFormat textstring

Tags: formatting, date-and-time

The appearance of a DateObject can be controlled by DateFormat, e.g. "Language". Is it possible to extract the text string so that in Style it appears the same as normal text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do = DateObject[{2022, 12, 19}, "Day"]
```

[image]

```
ds = DateString @ do
```

"Mon 19 Dec 2022"

```
Style[ds, Darker @ Blue, 16]
```

[image]

```
DateString[do, {"DayName", "  ", "Month", "/", "YearShort"}]
```

"Monday  12/22"